# Estimating distribution of marbles in a bag

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have $x$ marbles in a bag. I start drawing out marbles without replacement, and find that all of them are red.

How many consecutive red marbles would I have to draw out in order to conclude with 95% confidence that, say, at least 99% of the marbles in the bag are red?

I have found [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) on Wikipedia which seems related, but I am not sure how to apply it in this case, as I have no initial knowledge about the number of red marbles in the bag.

Comment: To be absolutely sure, you would need to take $99\%$ of the marbles out. But you have since edited the question to include "$95\%$ confidence".  At that point, you might think about the "[rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics))", suggesting that you might want about $300$ red marbles.

Comment: Let's say I don't want to go to that much trouble :-) Edited the question to add a confidence interval

Comment: To illustrate a difficulty, suppose I filled the bag with $99$ marbles, with each marble independently having an equal probability of being red or green, and you then took out $98$ red marbles (highly unlikely but possible).  The conditional probability of the last marble being green (so reds making up only $98.99\%$ of the original marbles) would be $50\%$.  To answer the question properly, you need a prior distribution for the number of marbles and conditioned on that for the number of red marbles.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful - I think the rule of three will be sufficient for my use case. Cheers